# Help finding a proof of an identity $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{n-k}{n \choose k}{n+k \choose k-1}=n$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Help finding a proof of an identity $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{n-k}{n \choose k}{n+k \choose k-1}=n$.
I have checked that the equality holds for n = 2,3,4,5,... etc. However I have no idea how to prove this identity for arbitrary n.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^a (-1)^{a-k} {a \choose k} {b+k \choose b+1} = {b \choose a-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638162/prove-that-sum-k-1a-1a-k-a-choose-k-bk-choose-b1-b-choose) (It's the same identity since, taking $b = a$, $(a + k) - (a + 1) = k - 1$.)

Comment: Perhaps induction over $n$

Comment: >prets: Yes, thank you very much! I haven't thought that we can use the Vandermode's identity for solving the problem. That's very cool!